# Overwriting native console.log function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, logging

I want to override the `console.log` function in order to save the data other scripts log. My script executes before any other script, so I have full control over the environment. This is my current function for overwriting `console.log`:

```
+function(){
    var a = Function.prototype, b = 'toString', c = a[b], d = c.apply(c).split(c.name), e = [], f = [], g = function(a, b){
        e.push(a);
        f.push(b);
        return a;
    }, _ = [];

    a[b] = function(h){
        return g(function toString(){
            var i = e.indexOf(this);
            return i != -1 ? f[i] || d.join(this.name) : h.apply(this);
        });
    }(c);

    console.log = function(a){
        return g(function log(){
            var b = [], i;
            for(i in arguments) b.push(arguments[i]);
                _.push(b.slice());
            return a.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    }(console.log);
}();
```

My question is simple: is it possible that some script executed after this can reveal that I have an overwritten `console.log` function?

I will use it for debugging scripts sent from users to my Node.js server application. I am using `vm` module, so I need to overwrite sandbox the object's `console.log` function in order to trace what users log to console in received scripts.

If this code looks obfuscated, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138478/overwriting-native-console-log-function-in-javascript/138486#138486) is a better version.

Comment: I don't like where you're going with this; you seem to be hacking around something that could be easily done via a decorator and I can't help but wonder just what you're using this for.

Comment: Also, yes, the debugger is able to get at the scopes

Comment: @Pimgd. The biggest problem of Stack Exchange sites is, I think, that users mostly vote questions by their assumption where OP will use answer. This is totaly, wrong, you cannot vote question because you assume I will use it for hacking. The real purpose I am looking for answer is because I want to execute scripts sent from users in my Node.js server application, but I want to find what they log to console in each script, nothing more than that.

Comment: @Pimgd. Also, debugger is not the problem, because other scripts cannot use debugger, it is available manually.

Comment: @Pimgd. Why it is so important where I will use it? Is it illegal to overwrite local browser function using available methods provided by Javascript? Oh, sorry, if it is illegal, I think someone should put me in a jail. You car report me to FBI saying "Hey, he has overwriten console.log function, arrest him immediately".

Comment: It's more of a thing where I'm worried that you're using this to run crap JS in my browser to dump a payload somewhere. But... yeah, assume good intentions. Anyway, add the context (that it's for executing scripts sent by users) to your question and I'll upvote. ... Oh, another question, what's the `+` at the start for?

Comment: @Pimgd. The plus sign before function is used to immediatelly execute function, if I remove it, syntax error will be thrown. Also, I edited question and added explanation where I will use the answer.

Comment: Looks good to me =)

Comment: If it is just for debugging, why are you so worried that the override might be detectable?

Comment: @200_success The user script is executed and return value is sent back to user. I want to make log tracing anonymous and undetectable by user, because I want to make sandox looks like original global object.

Comment: I recommend you fix your variable naming as per my answer and post a follow-up question, maybe there's something interesting in the internals that can be done better.

Comment: Given how obfuscated the code is I find it hard to believe that this is supposed to be entirely innocuous.

Comment: @Dannnno It is only my bad habit. I always used to write as short variable names as possible. I will edit the post to make it easier to be uderstood.

Comment: Please don't edit the post - we don't allow changing code after answers have been given. If you'd like further feedback please ask a new question.

Comment: @Dannnno. Can I add beautified code leaving old code too? Because, as you said, other users will find my code unuseful and hard to understand.

Comment: Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Basically, if you want other code reviewed, make a new question, and edit this one to have a link to the new question. We call those "follow-up questions".

Comment: @Pimgd I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, this is really clever, because inspecting `console.log` will still show `log() { [native code] }`

But then, what is this property `prototype` that is not present in the original `console.log`?

Even more interesting, in Chrome Canary, `console.log.prototype.constructor` will show the location of the implementation, which is clearly in user space:

```
Object
  constructor:log()
    arguments:null
    caller:null
    length:0
    name:"log"
    prototype:Object
    __proto__:()
    [[FunctionLocation]]:VM1191:16
    [[Scopes]]:Scopes[3]
  __proto__:Object
```

In node.js, the constructor just behaves weirdly and is indicative of weird things going on.

Furthermore, since this is codereview, the commonly accepted practice for immediately self executing is

```
(function functionName(arguments){ 
})();
```

That `+` is super hokey, and will be used in future codegolfing entries ;)

Comment: Very nicely spotted.

Answer (score 2):

I tried hacking around this in various ways and practically the only way I could detect it was wrapped was by having an old reference to `console.log` and using `===`. Since you state your code will run before any other scripts will run, this shouldn't be a problem.

That said, there's also `console.info`, `warn`, `trace`, so maybe you'd want to wrap those too?

From a code quality perspective, your variable naming needs work. You can haul it through a minifier later; what you have right now is unmaintainable. I don't even know what half of it does thanks to the variable naming.

Answer (score 1):

Because my original code looks very obfuscated and [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765) article says that OP is not allowed to edit code after accepting an answer, I am writing here beautified and easy-to-understand code:

```
+function(){
    var FunctionPrototype = Function.prototype;
    var toStr = 'toString';
    var originalFunc = FunctionPrototype[toStr];
    var namePattern = originalFunc.apply(originalFunc).split(originalFunc.name);
    var overwritenFuncs = [];
    var overwritenFuncsNames = [];
    var overwrite = function(originalFunction, overridenToStr){
        overwritenFuncs.push(originalFunction);
        overwritenFuncsNames.push(overridenToStr);
        return originalFunction;
    };
    var tracedLogs = [];

    FunctionPrototype[toStr] = function(h){
        return overwrite(function toString(){
            var i = overwritenFuncs.indexOf(this);
            return i != -1 ? overwritenFuncsNames[i] || namePattern.join(this.name) : h.apply(this);
        });
    }(originalFunc);

    console.log = function(originalConsoleLog){
        return overwrite(function log(){
            var b = [], i;
            for(i in arguments) b.push(arguments[i]);
            tracedLogs.push(b.slice());
            return originalConsoleLog.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    }(console.log);
}();
```

Comment: It's great that you added a non-minified version, but as an answer, it won't get reviewed. Are you okay with that?